# Startup processes errors

Tags: boot

I'am running "Raspberry Pi OS Lite (32 bit)" Released 2021-01-11 on a Raspberrypi 3 model B Rev 1.2. Running dmesg some warnings and errors are coming up.

**1) Direct firmware load for ... failed with error -2:**

```
[7.550384] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,3-model-b.txt failed with error -2
```

**2) module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned:**

```
[6.868235] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned. 
[6.871180] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned. 
[6.874997] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned. 
[6.887038] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned. 
[6.889205] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned. 
[6.900115] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13 
[6.900127] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
```

**3) I also have this (last 2 lines). Don't know if it is a problem:**

```
[2.728267] Core Release: 2.80a 
[2.730746] Setting default values for core params 
[2.733201] Finished setting default values for core params 
[2.936074] Using Buffer DMA mode 
[2.938541] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled 
[2.941085] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
```

I want to use the PI as a webserver so don't like to have a lot of errors.

Any ideas or reference to solutions ?

Comment: So what is the problem? Is something not working?

Comment: I am worried about performance at stability issues.

Comment: As per Ingo's answer logging copious amounts of information is a normal thing for computer systems, not all of it is relevant to all contexts (in fact, most of what is in the system logs is not relevant to most contexts).  It is mainly useful when you need to diagnose an actual problem -- unless you are aware of something specific you want to watch or look for.  That said, regularly paying attention to the logs -- even if most of it is gibberish -- will develop your eye for what's normal and what's not.

Comment: ...So *if* there are performance or stability issues, there's an important source of information.  But what you want to watch for are the actual issues, not the endless regress of things that you think *might* cause a problem because you aren't sure what their significance is.   I'm a control freak and I understand the desire to understand every detail of everything in order to maximise a feeling of safety, but at some point you have to let it go and put your provisional trust in something, at least until it proves unworthy ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about these "error" messages. They are shown on all installations.

**1) Direct firmware load for ... failed with error -2:**

is an attempt of the kernel to load the firmware before it is ready to accept firmware. The kernel repeats it later with success. You will find a message of it but that is a normal info and may be overseen.

**2) module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned:**

This seems to come because the module isn't official registered on an institution I don't know. But all other users of the installation will confirm, that it is working stable.

**3) I also have this (last 2 lines). Don't know if it is a problem:**

I cannot see any issues with this info messages. They only stated that enhacements for interrupts are disabled. Seems Raspberry Pi will use normal interupts because lack of enhacements?

By the way, I don't use `dmesg`, but `journalctl`. There you get better structured information including that from *dmesg*. Try:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=0 --priority=0..3
```

This will give you LOG_EMERG to LOG_ERR from the range of

```
0 = LOG_EMERG      system is unusable
1 = LOG_ALERT      action must be taken immediately
2 = LOG_CRIT       critical conditions
3 = LOG_ERR        error conditions
4 = LOG_WARNING    warning conditions
5 = LOG_NOTICE     normal, but significant, condition
6 = LOG_INFO       informational message
7 = LOG_DEBUG      debug-level message
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought dmesg was supposed to run without warnings and errors.

Comment: @Elmo: Anything but...

Comment: @Elmo I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As with all these things too much information is a bad thing when you have no clue how to decipher it. The only one there I can get is the you are warned this module has the possibility of being useless as it is from staging. The rest unless you are engineer you have no clue on. If the machine works as expected with them in place continue on with what you try to do.